# How to set properties in ControlTemplate children from XAML

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF, but have been trying to put together a demo app to illustrate how our product can improve by migrating away from a Forms MDI.

I have a template for a TabControl I've called "TabbedPanel" here for lack of a better name.  This TabbedPanel has two additional buttons: "Fullscreen" and "Close".  In the code below, you can see that I've attempted two different ways to bind the visibility of these buttons to a property, but neither works as expected.

```
<UserControl x:Class="myApp.TabbedPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TabControlControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Grid ClipToBounds="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD5D5D6" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF646464" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF606060"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="True" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
            <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectedContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedContent}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectedContentStringFormat}" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </Border>
            <Button Name="btnFullscreen" Content="FULLSCREEN" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="23" Margin="0,0,25.863,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" FontWeight="Bold" Click="btnFullscreen_Click" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=FullscreenButtonVisibility}">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF99945E" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.569"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.259"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFB4B04D" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="btnClose" Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="23" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25.863" BorderBrush="#FF2C0101" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Click="btnClose_Click" Visibility="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=CloseButtonVisibility}">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF850303" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF00000" Offset="0.5"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF720707" Offset="0.004"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF970000" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
    <TabControl Name="tabitems" Background="white" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Template="{DynamicResource TabControlControlTemplate1}">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItem_PreviewMouseMove"/>
                <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItem_Drop"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabControl">
                <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItem_PreviewMouseMove"/>
                <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItem_Drop"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
```

The following shows the relevant parts of the C# code.  I inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged and implement the interface for two properties: CloseButtonVisibility and FullscreenButtonVisibility.

```
public partial class TabbedPanel : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public TabbedPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler Close;
    public event RoutedEventHandler Fullscreen;

    private Visibility closeButtonVisibility;
    public Visibility CloseButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return closeButtonVisibility; }
        set 
        {
            SetField(ref closeButtonVisibility, value, "CloseButtonVisibility");
        }
    }

    private Visibility fullscreenButtonVisibility;
    public Visibility FullscreenButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return fullscreenButtonVisibility; }
        set
        {
            SetField(ref fullscreenButtonVisibility, value, "FullscreenButtonVisibility");
        }
    }

    public ItemCollection Tabs
    {
        get { return tabitems.Items; }
    }
```

I then use the TabbedPanel in the following code in MainWindow.xaml.  The FullscreenButtonVisibility and CloseButtonVisibility are then initialized to Visibility.Hidden.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:TabbedPanel Grid.Row="0" FullscreenButtonVisibility="Hidden" CloseButtonVisibility="Hidden">
            <local:TabbedPanel.Tabs>
                <TabItem Header="Top">
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="Artwork\ImageTop.JPG"/>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Left">
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="Artwork\ImageBottom.BMP"/>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Bottom">
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="Artwork\ImageLeft.JPG"/>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Right">
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Source="Artwork\ImageRight.JPG"/>
                </TabItem>
            </local:TabbedPanel.Tabs>
        </local:TabbedPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Using this, I expected the "Fullscreen" and "Close" buttons to start off as invisible, but they are shown.  I'm pretty sure I could procedurally set their visibility in C#, but it would be cleaner to do so via XAML.  Also, I'm pretty sure that I am missing some root WPF concept here that is throwing me off, but I've been teaching myself for only a few days...  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not the correct way to create Controls in WPF. I suggest you start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx) reading up on how to create Controls in WPF.

Comment: Can you be more specific in how it is incorrect?  I've read that article and others like it.  The reason I did it this way was because a control template was the only way I could figure out to get buttons on top of the TabControl header (off to the right).

Comment: you should not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `DependencyObject`-derived classes. If you need to create Custom properties, these properties must be DependencyProperties.